# Hexagon Bounds - Where to get or how to create?

Tags: qgis, hexagon-binning, hexagonal-grid

I was recently amazed to see Walkscore using what seems to be hexagon-shaped bounds to visualize crime data. [Reference website](http://blog.walkscore.com/2014/09/crime-grade-for-homes-and-apartments/#.Vm8qVhCrTGI). Any idea where they are getting the shapefile or ideas on how they are creating them?

[image: Hexagon bounds]

Comment: Those are hexagons.  Octagons cannot partition a space.

Comment: Possibly they got them from Warhammer 40k or a game-creator suite... gamers have been using hex grids since the 80's. They are regular shapes so each vertex is entirely predictable, it wouldn't be too difficult to emulate with code if you nominate an SDK; tools probably already exist online. Are you after the hex grid as GIS geometry file or an effect in Google maps?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson - Ahh W40k, that brings back memories :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use MMQGIS plugin in QGIS to create an hexagon grid. Take a look in this post from Anita Graser:

http://anitagraser.com/2012/03/04/mapping-density-with-hexagonal-grids/